# Spring Integration | Reactive Streams Support | Exception in creating a reactive Message Gateway

Tags: spring-integration, reactive-streams

I am trying to upgrade the spring integration flow in one of my existing application with Reactive Streams Support. The approach taken is to change the parameter and return type of the Gateway method as Mono. The flow executes smoothly and when the reply reaches the Gateway, it results in **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'beanFactory' must not be null**

I am using Spring Boot 2.3.0.

*inputChannel* is a *DirectChannel*

*gatewayReplyChannel* is a *FluxMessageChannel*

```
@MessagingGateway(name = "reactiveGateway")
public interface EntryGate {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "inputChannel", replyChannel = "gatewayReplyChannel")
    Mono<String> process(final Mono<String> input);

}
```

Exceptions trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'beanFactory' must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.ChannelUtils.getErrorHandler(ChannelUtils.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.ReactiveStreamsConsumer.onInit(ReactiveStreamsConsumer.java:155)
    at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(IntegrationObjectSupport.java:214)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.registerReplyMessageCorrelatorIfNecessary(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:806)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessageReactive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:609)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.sendOrSendAndReceive(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:639)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:573)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The `MessagingGatewaySupport.registerReplyMessageCorrelatorIfNecessary()` has to be fixed to call `endpoint.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);` for the `ReactiveStreamsConsumer`. Apparently we just don't have a test case to cover the `replyChannel` as a `FluxMessageChannel`.

Consider to not use that `replyChannel` at all as a workaround. It is really doesn't matter for this kind of flow: it is already reactive by the `Mono` return type. No reason to shift to other reactive stream internally for the reply correlation.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, by removing the replyChannel defined in Gateway.

Comment: Ok. I’ll push the fix soon and you tell me if that ok for you to accept the answer